Boilerplate.templ to wrap all my templates
I am using templ for templating my htmls. I really like templating I used to play with ejs for previous projects, I think ejs provides something like this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    

</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    
   <%- include("../partials/navbar") %>
    
    <main class="container mt-3 p-2">
        <%- include("../partials/flash")  %>
        <%- body -%>
    </main>
    
    <%- include("../partials/footer") %>

</body>

</html>


I can just include this boilerplate with the Include thing ejs provides
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') -%>
so I can just append any page with this boilerplate
I want something like this with templ
currently My boilerplate.templ looks like this
templ Boilerplate(){
    

    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.5.0"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="bg-gray-200" id="body">
            @partials.Navbar() 
            @Body()
        </body>
    </html>
}


idk here im embedding Body.templ into boilerplate but I want to Boilerplate.templ to wrap templates like Body.templ is it possible with templ???

What is the difference between "embedding Body.templ into boilerplate" and boilerplate wrapping "templates like Body.templ" (it sounds like you are already doing what you want?). I suspect your issue is the templ Boilerplate(){  (where are you running this?); as requested on your previous question please include a Minimal, Reproducable, Example so we can see the full (but simplified!) structure. The children section of the docs may be what you want.
